# Reader monad core operator not working

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a Reader monad but it does not work(load), what am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }

instance Monad (Reader r) where
    return a = Reader $ \r -> a

    Reader m >>= f = Reader $ \r ->
        let a = m r
        in runReader (f a)
```

I get this error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘r -> b’
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        (>>=) :: Reader r a -> (a -> Reader r b) -> Reader r b
      at Reader.hs:24:14
Expected type: Reader r b
  Actual type: Reader r (r -> b)
Relevant bindings include
  f :: a -> Reader r b (bound at Reader.hs:24:18)
  m :: r -> a (bound at Reader.hs:24:12)
  (>>=) :: Reader r a -> (a -> Reader r b) -> Reader r b
    (bound at Reader.hs:24:5)
In the expression: Reader $ \ r -> let a = ... in runReader (f a)
In an equation for ‘>>=’:
    (Reader m) >>= f = Reader $ \ r -> let ... in runReader (f a)
In the instance declaration for ‘Monad (Reader r)’
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: Please see the later edit

Comment: I think you might need parentheses `(Reader m)` when doing pattern matching

Comment: @genisage That is exactly the answer, and you should post it as such.

Comment: @Mokosha: Normally you would, but application (even in pattern matching) has higher precedence than `>>=`, so parentheses are not necessary there.

Comment: The right answer was (runReader (f a)) r I saw it earlier in a comment, I just wonder if it is correct, and why is it so. To who posted it first: put it as answer. I am also getting this warning ‘Reader’ is an instance of Monad but not Applicative - this will become an error in GHC 7.10, under the Applicative-Monad Proposal.

Comment: I was going to move it to an answer but then I realized I don't know how to explain it more clearly than ghci already did.

Comment: @genisage You could explain that it's correct because you're providing the same `r` to both `m` and the result of `f (m r)`, exactly what the reader monad is designed for.  You want it to use the exact same `r` for everything, and this definition of `>>=` means that has to hold.

Comment: @CosminMihai The warning about not being an instance of Applicative isn't too important for playing around, but if you were to make your custom reader monad into something to share on hackage, you would want to ensure that the applicative instance exists.  That also means you'll need a functor instance, but both of these are pretty straightforward after a bit of googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct implementation is:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }

instance Monad (Reader r) where
    return a = Reader $ \_ -> a
    Reader m >>= f = Reader $ \r -> runReader (f $ m r) r
```

The extra confusion that you're missing is the final `r` in the bind. Since this parameter is not there, it claims that you are mistaking an `r -> a` for an `a` when you are constructing the Reader (in other words, you have handed it an `r -> r -> a` when it wanted just an `r -> a`).

To see what's going on, it might help to examine the type of runReader:

```
ghci> :t runReader
runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a
```

This function takes as its first argument the reader, as its second argument an `r`, and gives you back an `a`. We can therefore see that the sub-expression

```
\r -> runReader (f $ m r) r
```

has type `r -> a` and is a good candidate to hand off to the `Reader` constructor. If you leave off that last `r` you have only applied `runReader` to one argument, and you get the curried `r -> a` function as a result, so that:

```
\r -> runReader (f $ m r)
```

has type `r -> r2 -> a` and when you feed it to a reader you'll obtain `Reader r (r2 -> a)`, which doesn't have the right type for `>>=`.